# Using Play! with Oracle

Tags: oracle, playframework

I am pretty new to Play! and I am thinking of using it for a small project of mine. One of the requirements of my project is to read system parameter from Oracle (using sysdba account) periodically, and store them a table. So I have to use JDBC connection with SQL query instead of JPA entity manager. So I'd like to know if Play! supports the usage of JDBC with raw SQL query, and if there is any sample codes. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

K.H

Comment: also, I wouldn't be using the sysdba account for this, create a view and grant a normal user access to this view, don't have applications logging in as sysdba.

Comment: Thanks Mathew! It's a good idea.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - just to be clear, it's also not a good idea to build a bespoke view in the SYS schema.  The appropriate thing to do is grant SELECT on V$PARAMETER to a regular user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fire native SQL [even using JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-jpql-087123.html)..

For your case, I would try something like below:

```
    String sql = "Select * from table where name = ?"; // native query
    Query query = JPA.em().createNativeQuery(sql);
    query.setParameter(1, "some name");
    query.setMaxResults(1); // this 
    return query.getResultList();
```

The Query is

> javax.persistence.Query

Comment: Thanks basav! I'll try out with JPA native query.